Examples of when minimal generating sets may only have one cardinality
Given a variety of algebras, one can ask the following question: are the cardinalities of minimal generating sets of models of this variety unique? This is the case for vector spaces and unary algebras, but not for, say, groups: $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has minimal generating sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 3\}$.
Are there any other interesting examples or characterizations of varieties like vector spaces and unary algebras, whose models always have a fixed cardinality for their minimal generating sets?
Reference: chapter 2, section 4 of A Course in Universal Algebra by Burris and Sankappanavar.

Are there any other interesting examples or characterizations of varieties like vector spaces and unary algebras, whose models always have a fixed cardinality for their minimal generating sets?
Let me first reduce this question to one about finitely generated algebras.
Claim. If $\mathbf{A}$ has minimal generating subsets $X$ and $Y$
and one subset is finite, then the other is finite. If they are both infinite,
then $|X|=|Y|$.
Reasoning. For each $y\in Y$ we have $y\in \langle X\rangle$,
so $y\in \langle X_y\rangle$ for some finite subset $X_y\subseteq X$.
This means that $\mathbf{A}=\langle Y\rangle=\langle \cup_{y\in Y} X_y\rangle$,
proving that $\cup_{y\in Y} X_y$ is a generating subset
for $\mathbf{A}$ that is contained in $X$.
Since $X$ is a minimal generating subset, $X =\cup_{y\in Y} X_y$.
If $Y$ is finite, then $\cup_{y\in Y} X_y$ is finite, so $X$ is finite.
A similar argument shows that if $X$ is finite, then $Y$ is finite.
Now assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are infinite.
Since $|X_y|\leq\omega$ for each $y\in Y$ we get
$|X|=|\cup_{y\in Y} X_y|\leq |Y|\cdot\omega=|Y|$,
so $|X|\leq |Y|$.
A similar argument shows that $|Y|\leq |X|$, hence
$|X|=|Y|$. \\\ 
This shows that if $\mathcal{V}$ is a variety whose
finitely generated members
have 'unique rank' in the sense of this question, then
all members of $\mathcal{V}$ will
have unique rank in the sense of this question.

Let me list some examples of varieties whose finitely generated members
have 'unique rank' in the sense of this question:


Any locally finite variety of $p$-groups.


Any variety of modules over a finite local ring.


Any locally finite variety of nilpotent semigroups.


To see why any locally finite variety of $p$-groups
has the property that finitely generated (=finite)
members have uniquely determined rank,
assume that $P$ is a finite $p$-group.
Let $X$ be any minimal generating subset of $P$.
If $\Phi_P$ is the Frattini subgroup of $P$, then,
by the Burnside Basis Theorem,
$X/\Phi_P$ is a minimal generating for
the elementary abelian $p$-group $P/\Phi_P\cong \oplus^r\mathbb Z_p$.
Moreover, $|X/\Phi_P|=|X|$.
This explains why the size of a minimal generating
subset for $P$ has size equal to the $\mathbb Z_p$-dimension
of $P/\Phi_P$, hence explains why any two minimal generating
subsets have the same size.
The other varieties I listed also satisfy a Burnside Basis-type
theorem, which can be used in the same way.
More generally, all of the arguments given
are satisfied by any locally finite variety of E-minimal algebras.
An algebra $\mathbf{A}$ is E-minimal
if $1<|A|<\infty$ and every idempotent unary polynomial
of $\mathbf{A}$ is constant or the identity.
(A unary polynomial of $\mathbf{A}$ is a function $p(x)$
constructed from a term operation $t(x,\bar{y})$ by substituting
parameters $\bar{a}\in A^n$ for all variables but $1$:
$p(x)=t^{\mathbf{A}}(x,\bar{a})$. It is idempotent if
$p(p(x))=p(x)$.) The examples above are locally finite
varieties of E-minimal algebras.

Let me close with some examples that do not have the unique rank property.


The variety of Boolean algebras.


The variety of distributive lattices.


Any locally finite variety of groups that is not a variety of $p$-groups.


Any variety of modules over a finite ring $R$ that is not a local ring.


Explanation:
(1) The $n$-generated free Boolean algebra has $2^n$
atoms. The atoms form a generating subset, but it is not minimal.
However, if you delete on atom, then you do get a minimal generating
subset. This yields a minimal generating subset of size $n$
(the free generators) and a second minimal generating subset
of size $2^n-1$.
(2) For distributive lattices, let $L$ be the underlying
lattice of the $n$-generated free Boolean algebra.
If the set of Boolean generators is $X= \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, then
the set
$X\cup \neg X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n,\neg x_1,\ldots,\neg x_n\}$
is a set of lattice generators that has size $2n$.
This set must contain a minimal generating subset
of size at most $2n$.
The set of atoms of $L$ is a minimal lattice-generating
subset of size $2^n$.
(3) Any locally finite variety of groups
that does not consist entirely of $p$-groups
for some prime $p$ must contain
$\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_q$ for some primes $p\neq q$,
so $\mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_q \cong \mathbb Z_{pq}$
has minimal generating subsets of sizes 1 and 2, as
in the problem statement.
(4) If $R$ is a finite ring that is not a local ring, then
$R$ has distinct maximal ideals $I$ and $J$. The $R$-module
$R/I\times R/J$ has a $1$-element minimal generating subset
$\{(\bar{1},\bar{1})\}$ and also a $2$-element minimal generating subset
$\{(\bar{1},\bar{0}),(\bar{0},\bar{1})\}$.

Thank you very much for this answer! My question was quite open-ended, but this points to interesting roads to go down. Some of this goes beyond my current knowledge, but I will probably return to this answer in the future when I am more familiar with the Burnside basis theorem, etc., especially because you made sure to explain what everything means.

It's always a delight to read your answers, but this time I got confused. Would you please elucidate me? The reason is that, as far as I think I understand, a variety in a countable language is one in which we have countably many operations. But the examples you provide all have finitely many ones. If on the other hand, countable language would mean finite or countably infinite, then it would include the three non-examples and indeed, everything that is usually studied. So where am I getting wrong?

@amrsa: Let me rewrite the first paragraph.

Ok, although I had understood the reasoning before. That piece of semantics related to countability of the language was the one that got me confused. Now it's all clear to me. Thanks!

Semilattices.
If $S$ is a finite semilattice, and $U$ is the set of its irreducible elements, i.e., $u \in U$ if $u=ab$, with $a,b \in S$ always imply that $u=a$ or $u=b$.
Then $U$ is the only minimal generating set of $S$.
Indeed, it's clear that $U$ generates $S$, but if $V \subseteq S$ is such that $U \nsubseteq V$, and $u \in U\setminus V$, then there are no elements $v,w \in V$ such that $u=vw$ (by definition of $U$).
So finite semi lattices also have a dimension.

Quasi-trivial magmas are magmas in which $xy \in \{x,y\}$, for all $x$ and $y$.
In these, the only minimal generating set is the magma itself.
But these don't form a variety.
However, among these there are
Left-zero semigroups.
These are semigroups satisfying $xy=x$.
And then, of course, the same applies to
Right-zero semigroups, which are defined by the equation $xy=y$.
Now, while both varieties above are rather trivial in some sense, their join (the least variety of semigroups containing both), is not composed only of quasi-trivial semigroups.
That is the variety of
Rectangular bands.
These are defined by the equation $xyx=x$, but a rectangular band can also be described as a semigroup which is the direct product of a left-zero and a right-zero semigroup.
So if $S$ is a rectangular band, $S = L \times R$, where $L$ is a left-zero semigroup and $R$ is a right-zero semigroup.
In the finite case, suppose, without loss of generality, that $L=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and $R=\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\}$, with $1\leq n \leq m$.
It follows that no generating set for $S$ has less than $m$ elements, where each of the $b_j$ must be the second component of one of them.
Indeed, if there is no element $(a,b_{j_0})$ in a generating set $X$, with $a \in L$ and for some $j_0 \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$, then $(u,v)\cdot(u',v')=(u,v') \neq (a,b_{j_0})$.
On the other hand, $S$ is generated by
$$\{(a_i,b_i):1\leq i\leq n\} \cup \{(a_n,b_i):n<i\leq m\},$$
which has $m$ elements.
To see that the above set generates $S$, observe that, if $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j \leq m$, then
$$(a_i,b_j) = (a_i,b_i) \cdot (a_j,b_j),$$
where, for notational simplicity, we make the convention that $a_{n+1},\ldots,a_m$ take the value $a_n$.
So, if $S=L\times R$ is a rectangular band, with $|L|=n$ and $|R|=m$, then $S$ has minimal generating sets (more than one, if both $n$ and $m$ are greater than $1$) of size $\max\{n,m\}$.

Semilattices, right-zero and left-zero semigroups and rectangular bands are all varieties of bands (idempotent semigroups), of which there are infinitely many.
I wonder if some, at least at the bottom of the lattice of varieties of bands, share this property.
The same could also be for other varieties of magmas with are not semigroups;
perhaps even the idempotency of the operation ($x\cdot x = x$) is not necessary, although it makes it easier.

I don't think it works in the infinite case. The completely irreducible elements don't need to generate everything.

In the finite case your proof is lacking the step to prove that the set of irreducible elements is the unique minimal generating set.

@MartinBrandenburg You're right! They don't necessarily generate everything unless we'd consider an infinitary version of the operation, which doesn't make sense. Concerning the set of irreducible elements being the only minimal generating set, I thought it was evident, but maybe it's not. But it's just the same argument used to show that a proper subset won't work; we need those irreducible elements in any generating set.

As the OP, I should probably write out my proof of the exercise given in the text that unary algebras have unique cardinality of minimal genset, especially because it goes slightly beyond the generality of the text.
Let $A$ and $B$ be minimal gensets of a model of a unary algebra. Every $b \in B$ can be written as $f_1(f_2(\ldots f_n(a)\ldots))$ with $a \in A$ for some composition of operations. This produces a map $\varphi \colon B \rightarrow A$ and it must be surjective, or else $A$ is not minimal, as we can generate the model with $\operatorname{im} \varphi$. Therefore, we have surjections from $B$ to $A$ and $A$ to $B$ by a mirror argument, as desired.
